# How to show upload progress percentage in dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, magento, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js in magento to upload files. the progress bar is working fine but i want to show the progress percentage too. Following function is adding style to a span.

```
uploadprogress: function(a, b) {
                var c, d, e, f, g;
                if (a.previewElement) {
                    for (f = a.previewElement.querySelectorAll("[data-dz-uploadprogress]"), g = [], d = 0, e = f.length; e > d; d++) c = f[d], g.push("PROGRESS" === c.nodeName ? c.value = b : c.style.width = "" + b + "%");
                    return g
                }
            },
```

which add the style="width:xx%" in the following html.

I also want to show the % result which g return in above code in span as text so that the user can see the numbers too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you have a span in your progress bar for example like this:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" data-dz-uploadprogress>
        <span class="progress-text"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You should define your uploadprogress function as follows:

```
uploadprogress: function(file, progress, bytesSent) {
    if (file.previewElement) {
        var progressElement = file.previewElement.querySelector("[data-dz-uploadprogress]");
        progressElement.style.width = progress + "%";
        progressElement.querySelector(".progress-text").textContent = progress + "%";
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well. I want to add to this solution solution so whoever is reading this may want to know it goes in the options, so to add to the options do this: `Dropzone.options.dropzoneIDHere = {
  uploadprogress: function(file, progress, bytesSent) {
  }
};`

Comment: What is a.previewElement in this case? It's not defined in your code

Comment: @Ben, Ideally it should be `file.previewElement`. 
Even after that if you face any error of querySelector being `null`, use following line instead of querySelector line (or equivalent js line, if no jquery)
`$(".progress-text").text(progress + "%")`

Comment: It should be `if (file.previewElement) {`

Answer (score 3):

So many ways to skin a cat... Is there anything wrong with my implementation which seems to work? Although the percentage is in no way rounded "10.12345678%".

```
myDropzone.on("totaluploadprogress", function (progress) {
  $("#the-progress-div").width(progress + '%');
  $(".the-progress-text").text(progress + '%');
});
```

I use this in the html:

```
<div id="the-progress-div">
  <span class="the-progress-text"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to use `progress.toFixed(2)` for the percentages to be rounded to 2 decimals.

Comment: If you choose to use this,the function now takes three args, (file, progress, bytesSent)