# How to show uploading percentage of a file using Dropzone js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

i am using Dropzone js for file uploading. I want to display the uploading percentage with progress bar. I know the Dropzone js is not supporting to display the percentage by default.
show i define the code for get the progress value and try to show in class `.dropzone-progress-total`. This class is not get anything yet. can anybody tell how can i get the percentage and display it?

**html**

```
<div class="dropzone-percentage">
    <span class="dropzone-progress-total"></span>
</div>
```

**js**

```
// Update the total progress bar
myDropzone.on("totaluploadprogress", function (progress) {
    $(this).find(id + " .progress-bar").css("width", progress + "%");
    $(this).find(id + " .dropzone-progress-total").text(progress + "%"); // this line is not working
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show upload progress percentage in dropzone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620641/how-to-show-upload-progress-percentage-in-dropzone-js)

Comment: Dear i also read about that guy but my ui situation is diffrent. can you please help me on this line of code `$(this).find(id + " .dropzone-progress-total").text(progress + "%");`